# How to send image using AIDL between two processes?

Tags: android, parcelable, aidl

First of all, I know that generally AIDL supports primitive data type such as Integer, String and Map, etc. Also, with Parcelable type being introduced, higher level data type can be treated as well.

Now I wonder if sending image between two processes using AIDL is possible. I've tried that before, but packaging the Parcelable class is not easy for me. If anyone knows the solution please help me!

--update 2016/2/26--

Here "image" represents image type file, like "jpg" or "png".

Comment: Please explain, in greater detail, the nature of the "image". Do you mean a `Bitmap`? Do you mean a `File`? Do you mean a `byte[]`? Do you mean a URL? Do you mean a `Uri`? Do you mean something else?

Comment: I've updated the description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

I use "byte[]" as the tranfer medium between two processes, so I don't even need to implement the parcelable class.

Here is my
[demo code](https://github.com/ymjiang/AIDL-transfer-Image-example).

Answer (score 0):

> Now I wonder if sending image between two processes using AIDL is possible

According to your question, you do not want to send an image between two processes. You want to send a URL between two processes. A URL can be represented as a `String`, and AIDL supports passing `String` values between processes.

Comment: However, I need to fetch the image when it has been downloaded completely in another process. And that's why I have the problem

Comment: @ymjiang: Then your "--Update--" is misleading. When you download the image, you will either have a `byte[]` in memory or a file on disk. If the `byte[]` is small (under 1MB), you are welcome to pass the `byte[]` via AIDL. However, the transaction size for this sort of IPC establishes a hard 1MB cap, so if there is any chance that your image data would exceed that cap, you are better off writing it to a file, then having your other process read in the file.